# ListView drag&drop re-order for ListView in "details" view code usage

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

This questions has nothing in common with [Reorder / move / dragdrop ListViewItems within the same ListView Control in C# Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405328/reorder-move-dragdrop-listviewitems-within-the-same-listview-control-in-c-sh) because it will only work for large/small icons view mode!

I found some nice little code here:

http://snipplr.com/view/33427/

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace System.Windows.Forms // May need to set to something else
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A ListView with DragDrop reordering.
    /// <see cref="http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822483/en-us"/>
    /// </summary>
    public class ListViewWithReordering : ListView
    {
        protected override void OnItemDrag(ItemDragEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnItemDrag(e);
            //Begins a drag-and-drop operation in the ListView control.
            this.DoDragDrop(this.SelectedItems, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }

        protected override void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs drgevent)
        {
            base.OnDragEnter(drgevent);
            int len = drgevent.Data.GetFormats().Length - 1;
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i <= len; i++)
            {
                if (drgevent.Data.GetFormats()[i].Equals("System.Windows.Forms.ListView+SelectedListViewItemCollection"))
                {
                    //The data from the drag source is moved to the target. 
                    drgevent.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
                }
            }

        }

        protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs drgevent)
        {
            base.OnDragDrop(drgevent);
            //Return if the items are not selected in the ListView control.
            if (this.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            //Returns the location of the mouse pointer in the ListView control.
            Point cp = this.PointToClient(new Point(drgevent.X, drgevent.Y));
            //Obtain the item that is located at the specified location of the mouse pointer.
            ListViewItem dragToItem = this.GetItemAt(cp.X, cp.Y);
            if (dragToItem == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            //Obtain the index of the item at the mouse pointer.
            int dragIndex = dragToItem.Index;
            ListViewItem[] sel = new ListViewItem[this.SelectedItems.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i <= this.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                sel[i] = this.SelectedItems[i];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < sel.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                //Obtain the ListViewItem to be dragged to the target location.
                ListViewItem dragItem = sel[i];
                int itemIndex = dragIndex;
                if (itemIndex == dragItem.Index)
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (dragItem.Index < itemIndex)
                    itemIndex++;
                else
                    itemIndex = dragIndex + i;
                //Insert the item at the mouse pointer.
                ListViewItem insertItem = (ListViewItem)dragItem.Clone();
                this.Items.Insert(itemIndex, insertItem);
                //Removes the item from the initial location while 
                //the item is moved to the new location.
                this.Items.Remove(dragItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which is based on / was adapted from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4576/Drag-and-Drop-ListView-row-reordering.

Unfortunately the code download doesn't work.

However - how is this code beeing used? Simply pasting it in my forms-class won't work. I supposed this code simply overrides all drag events from all listviews within a form?!

Sorry this is such a stupid question, but how do I use this code?

Comment: You realize it is a class on its own, right? It needs to go in it's own file

Comment: Sure. That's what I tried. But where / how is the invocation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone has kindly taken the standard .NET ListView control and used something called Inheritance to make their own version with extra functionality. You should read up on it, it's a useful thing to know.

To get it to work in your project you need to add this class as described below.

I assume you're using Visual Studio, you haven't mentioned otherwise.

1. In Solution Explorer on the right hand side Right Click on your
   solution and go to Add > Class.
2. Name the class whatever you like (ListViewWithReordering.cs would
   make the most sense) and then open that file. Past all of this code
   into the file.
3. Where it says `namespace` at the top you'll want to edit this to
   match your own programs namespace.
4. Build your project.
5. In the Toolbox on the left where you normally see all of the
   standard .NET controls there should be a section at the top that now
   contains `ListViewWithReordering`.
6. Drag this control onto your project.
7. Done! Use it like any other ListView control. The rest should work automatically (as long as this class is indeed reliable).

Comment: Thank you Equlsk. I know what inheritance is, but I didn't know, that you can override standard win-forms in such a easy way o.O

Comment: And I didn't expect it to appear under "LoginView-Components" :)

Comment: No problem. It's one of those "it's easy when you know how" problems. Have fun!

Comment: A few mods are needed to make this control work. AutoArrange needs to be set to false to allow drag and drop within ListViewWithReordering control, and the control needs to be refreshed from outside the Drop event to show the re-ordered images. I do this with a timer and change the control View mode to Tile and then back to whichever of LargeIcon and SmallIcon was used. Control and ImageLists need explicit Dispose after form containing it is closed to avoid Out of Memory problem on reentry.

Comment: +1 I knew about _overriding standard winforms_ pretty well, but apparently _not as well as I thought.._ Learn something new everyday, right? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I created a design example of drag and drop, download the project on the following link. Any questions ask again.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B21l6Fz0byBMSi1VTm52V2E4VVE/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-jNA3sA85A6lygH3TyISstA

Comment: Thanks for your code. Unfortunately is the code from my initial post not working properly... And it's from Microsoft.

Answer (score -1):

First add this class to your project.

Then, If you already have a listview from the forms designer, go to the InitializeComponent() method of your form constructor. There your listview is declared as:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ListView listView1;
```

Change this declaration to:

```
private ListViewWithReordering listView1;
```

Comment: don't touch the generated file.